# NGINX/Openshift - Location block redirecting to wrong port

Tags: redirect, nginx, openshift

I have an NGINX running on port `8443` inside a Docker container within Openshift. I also have an Openshift route defined that forwards traffic from port `443` to the container's `8443`.

This works fine until I try to access a location block without a trailing `/` on the URL. For instance, when I go to:

`https://test.example.com/example`

The JS network logs show NGINX is trying to redirect me to the wrong port (`8443`):

`https://test.example.com:8443/example/`

Since the only port that is exposed publicly is `443`, this fails. FWIW, it works fine when adding the trailing slash (`https://test.example.com/example/`)

Is there a way to get NGINX to not use its internal port during redirects, and instead stick with the port the client used? Here's an example of my location block:

```
location /example {
  proxy_pass https://example.apps.svc.cluster.local:8443;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer in the [HttpCoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule) docs. Had to include `port_in_redirect off;` in the location block. For example:

```
location /example {
  port_in_redirect off;
  proxy_pass https://example.apps.svc.cluster.local:8443;
}
```